# Avoid duplicate role execution

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook like

```yaml
- hosts: hostA
  roles:
    - roleA
    - roleB

- hosts: hostB
  roles:
    - roleA
    - roleC
```

and an inventory

```yaml
all:
  children:
    hostA:
      hosts:
        machine1
    hostB:
      hosts:
        machine2
```

So far, everything works fine. But now I have a second environment with inventory

```yaml
all:
  children:
    hostA:
      hosts:
        machine3
    hostB:
      hosts:
        machine3
```

`RoleA` gets executed twice when I run the playbook. Is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 2):

The most DRY, straightforwad and easy way to "fix" this is:

```yaml
- name: run common roles for both groups
  hosts: hostA:hostB
  roles:
    - roleA

- name: run specific roles for group A
  hosts: hostA
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - roleB

- name: run specific roles for group B
  hosts: hostB
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - roleC
```

If you are unclear with the meaning of `hosts: hostA:hostB` in the first play, have a look at [ansible hosts/group patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html)

Comment: very nice answer!